# Overriding core template files from module

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I'm a learning addon developer for Prestashop. I have been trying to solve this for a long time, how do you properly override a template file from a module? At the moment I'm overriding the entire file by copying the template file in the override folder from my module on installation:

From:

```
/modules/<module>/views/templates/admin/products/informations.tpl
```

To:

```
/override/controllers/admin/templates/products/informations.tpl
```

Overriding the whole file just to add an input field seems pretty rough.

This works just fine, but I'm worried because if the user installs some other module that wants to use the same file and it corrupts or Prestashop's new version changes the file and it doesn't support the new version anymore. In every way that feels like a dirty solution to the problem.

Is there a way to override just a part of the file and maybe directly from the module folder? Is there any better way to do this? How do you do this?

Comment: Use JS for this. Make a TPL file which contains your new div/input and then insert the content wherever you want. `$('#my_div').insertAfter('#element_id');`

Answer (score 2):

To override templates in PrestaShop you need to override the `hookDisplayOverrideTemplate` method from your modules controller.

To register your hook, add this to your install function:

`$this->registerHook('DisplayOverrideTemplate');`

now add your own version of the function to server your .tpl file.

```
public function hookDisplayOverrideTemplate($params)
{
    $controllerName = get_class($params['controller']);
    $tpl = dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/templates/override/example.tpl';
    if ($controllerName == 'ExampleController' && file_exists($tpl)) 
        return $tpl;
    return false;
}
```

In my example, you need to place your template you want to override with inside your modules `/views/template/override` folder.

When a page is loaded the front controller, `classes/controller/FrontController.php`, calls the `hookDisplayOverrideTemplate` function and if a template is returned, it will be loaded, otherwise it loads the default template.

I have tested this and know it works for PrestaShop v1.5 and v1.6

Answer (score 0):

If your module needs to change some code in .tpl file it will be better to do it in oryginal .tpl and put there IF-ELSE statement that will add your input field only if module is on. You cannot avoid destroying those files when someone will update the script.

You can think about some JS solution that will add the input on the client side.

Comment: Hope you are not right :D I wish they would implement something as easy as for the controllers and classes..